# How to mix "this" and strings in a jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery, html

This is my html code:

```
<div class="floor">
    <div id="article">
        <h2>TextFirst</h2>
        <img src="pic1.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="article">
        <h2>TextSecond</h2>
        <img src="pic2.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="article">
        <h2>TextThird</h2>
        <img src="pic3.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to do this with JQuery:
When hover mouse on exact #article's image then the same #acticle's h2 fades. How can I do that?

Here's my JQuery code:

```
$('.floor #article img').hover(function() {
    $(this - 'img' + 'h2').stop(true, false).animate({color: '#4099FF'}, $animatespeed);
}, function() {
    $(this - 'img' + 'h2').stop(true, false).animate({color: '#000000'}, $animatespeed);
});
```

I know that this doesn't work, but this was my idea, how I could make it done. Any help, please?

Comment: ID of an element should be unique.

Comment: You have too many `</div>` by the way

Comment: Change `$(this - 'img' + 'h2')` to `$('img h2', this)`

Comment: This is one of the most creative workarounds to the site's title filter I've ever seen...

Answer (score 3):

First ID of an element must be unique, so use class attribute for `article`(you have multiple elements with the id `article`)

```
<div class="floor">
    <div class="article">
         <h2>TextFirst</h2>
        <img src="pic1.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="article">
     <h2>TextSecond</h2>
    <img src="pic2.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="article">
     <h2>TextThird</h2>
    <img src="pic3.jpg" />
</div>
```

then your selector is wrong, `this` inside the event handler is a dom reference, so you cannot use it for string concatenation, the `h2` element you are looking for is the sibling element of the hovered element so you can use `.sibling()` as shown below

```
$('.floor .article img').hover(function() {
    $(this).siblings('h2').stop(true, false).animate({color: '#4099FF'}, $animatespeed);
}, function() {
    $(this).siblings('h2').stop(true, false).animate({color: '#000000'}, $animatespeed);
});
```

Comment: Might want to fix the amount of `</div>`s if you're going to supply new HTML code. **Update for OP:-** note the difference in closing div tags (`</div>`)

Answer (score 1):

Your html is wrong - extra `</div>` under every  `div#article`. You cannot bind jquery handler to multiple elements with the same id (only the first fill be bound) -> use classes instead

```
<div class="floor">
    <div class="article">
        <h2>TextFirst</h2>
        <img src="pic1.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="article">
        <h2>TextSecond</h2>
        <img src="pic2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="article">
        <h2>TextThird</h2>
        <img src="pic3.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

You jquery selector is wrong use something like this.

```
$('.floor .article img').hover(function() {
    $(this).siblings('h2').fadeOut();
}, function() {
    $(this).parent().find('h2').fadeIn();
});
```